# JS - Display either image or video with instanceof?

Tags: javascript, php, cloudinary

I'm getting the cloudinary image/video ID like this:

```
<?php echo cloudinary_url($_upload->getPublicId()); ?>
```

which gives a URL like: 
http://res.cloudinary.com/dviiu412p/image/upload/v1/campaigns/1/jfle7ilxkyfmj9mjggwa

And then rendering it out as an image or video like so:

```
<img class="lazy-load"
    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
    data-src="<?php echo cloudinary_url($_upload->getPublicId()); ?>" />

<video class="lazy-load" controls>
    <source data-src="<?php echo cloudinary_url($_upload->getPublicId(), array("resource_type"=>video, "height"=>230, "width"=>340, "format"=>webm)); ?>" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

The problem is I only want to serve either an image or video (whichever one was uploaded by the user). Is there a way I can achieve this? I was thinking instanceof might be able to do this but I've never used it before. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the source of `$_upload` is the upload response than you'd have the `resource_type` value as well. You need the value of `resource_type` coupled with the public ID to distinguish between resources (image, video or raw). You can then use a switch-case block to generate the correct tag.

For example,

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

switch ($result["resource_type"]) {
  case "image":
    // generate image tag
    break;
  case "video":
    // generate video tag
    break;
}
```